# How to deploy in amazon ec2 through bitbucket

Tags: amazon-ec2, deployment, git, django

I have a django project and  have my repository in bitbucket and locally (windows 7). Now I want to deploy the changes to amazon ec2 instance (ubuntu 14.04) by doing `git push` and `git pull`. I did git clone and have added it. But I can't do `git pull` nor can I `git push` from the ec2 instance. What do I have to do to push or atleast pull from the origin master.

I guess its a very simple question. But I am a newbie so very confused. Please elaborate your answer. I would be very helpful if you could help me. Thank you.

Comment: What kind of error message do you get?

Comment: What's your error messages?

Comment: @Bazze Thank you so much for your respond. I just had to git -config user.username "Name" and git -config user.email email.

Comment: @CloudWeavers Thank you so much for your respond. I just had to git -config user.username "Name" and git -config user.email email.

Comment: @Robin: Okay, cool. Post it as an answer and accept it! :)